# Percent sign in bash is not typeable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

I have a strange problem: I cannot type or copy the percent sign in my bash...

I tried to read `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` (and stuff in `/etc/profile.d`). I also tried `sudo bash`, but still not possible to type "%". Percent sign in `sh` works...

Checked also the key mapping: `xmodmap -pke | grep percent` gives `keycode 14 = 5 percent 5 percent`. If I change the key mapping for example with `xmodmap -e "keycode 14 = 5 U203D 5 UD203D"`, it prints the character `‽` when pressing `SHIFT+5`

Also strange: I even can not copy the %-sign from clipboard into the Terminal.

Any suggestions?

`cat ~/.inputrc`

```
$include /etc/inputrc
%"\e[5~": history-search-backward
%"\e[6~": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

`cat /etc/inputrc`

```
# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

# set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
# set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
# set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

$if term=rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux 3.2.0-65-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:03:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BTW: The question was orginally asked on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362965/percent-sign-in-bash-is-not-typeable

Comment: Is this from the local terminal/screen/keyboard or from a remote login, and if the latter which client are you using? What type of keyboard (physical layout) are you using?

Comment: Its local, but also is the case for remote ssh sessions (if I use my Mac to connect I get a 'beep' if I try to type a % sign). The keyboard layout is german.

Comment: is this typing from the Ubuntu gui? do you get the same problem if you boot Ubuntu recovery mode to a console screen (not a window inside the gui)? I wonder if you have mapped/hotkeyed % somehow to some special action?

Comment: Do you have a ~/.inputrc file, and if so what's in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the % from the lines

```
%"\e[5~": history-search-backward
%"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

in your `inputrc` file. Those are defining a keyboard sequence starting with the `%` key, and they will basically have the consequence of making that key unusable. If you remove the `%`, then the lines will associate history-search with the PageUp and PageDn keys.